# Router context undefined with BrowserRouter in react-router-dom v5

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Have an issue where the following code successfully logs the context when using `react-router-dom` `4.0.0`, but logs `undefined` when using `5.0.1`.

```
const { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } = window.ReactRouterDOM;

const PropTypes = window.PropTypes;

class Main extends React.Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  }

  render() {
    console.log("this.context.router");
    console.log(this.context);
    console.log(this.context.router);

    return <div>Main</div>;
  }
}

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Main} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

using: `4.0.0` (works):
https://jsfiddle.net/2shm7awn/3/

using: `5.0.1` (doesn't work):
https://jsfiddle.net/2shm7awn/2/

using `5.0.1` and every other package up to date (`react`/`react-dom` @ `16.9.0` - also doesn't work):

https://jsfiddle.net/2shm7awn/5/

I've done a fair amount of searching, and even if I missed something obvious in the docs, I think this could help some in the future.

Is there something new with version 5 that I'm missing?

Comment: If I'm not wrong that info are in the props

Comment: @GabrielMartinezBustos it is in the props, but in v4 it's accessible via the context and the props

Comment: Hello, any updates on this? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @AliMajed unfortunately I was never able to solve it.  We ended up going with another solution.  Can't remember what that solution was.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the reason is that React Router 5 uses the new context API, which is different from the old one. You can find some information here:
[react router v5](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5/) and some points how to access it [accessing context api](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12397)

But why do you need to access the context this way? Probably the problem can be solved in another way.

Comment: Hmm well this does use the new context api: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype

Comment: But to answer your question, I'm having a bug where Link is throwing an error (says context.router is `undefined`).  It is deeply nested in a component that I pull from another project.  So not entirely sure what is going on.  Although I don't think I've wrapped my head enough around that bug to write up a question yet.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this when I had a inexplicable failure after upgrading from v4 to v5. So to add to @sergii-vorobei's answer for anyone it might help.

My issue was because one of the package dependencies from generating the routes was bundling react-router in its distributable. Since react-router depends on the singleton for supplying the correct context, the singleton for the main app router and routes did not match leading to the routes never receiving the context from the main app.